# Why am I unable to convert this json into a string?

Tags: javascript

I have json data I'm having difficulty turning into a string. How can I format it so that it can become strings?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s97QX/2/

code:

```
Jsonvar = {"shows":[{"show_id":6387, "shownum":6387,"title":"The Protestant's  Dilemma","guest":"Devin Rose","category":"Non-Catholic","url":"http://www.catholic.com/radio/shows/the-protestants-dilemma-11565","audiourl":"http://www.catholic.com/sites /default/files/audio/radioshows/ca140331b.mp3","datetime":"1396317600","description":"
Devin Rose <\/p>","thumbnailsmall":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_small/images/profilepics/a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg","thumbnaillarge":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/profile_square_large/images/profilepics  /a109aad8daa70ad8976ffc.L._V387899120_SX200_.jpg"}]};

var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(Jsonvar);
alert(jsonstr);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s97QX/4/

Comment: @PranavSingh You've removed the error with your edit

Comment: @Andreas, I just formatted json for better understanding, sorry if it removed error.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Invalid JSON]

First You validate your json using jsonlint.
[JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/)
 then try.

Answer (score 2):

This error in the console explains it:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

You have a line break in your object:

```
Jsonvar = {"shows":[{"show_id":6387, "shownum":6387,"title":"The Protestant's     Dilemma","guest":"Devin Rose","category":"Non-
Catholic","url":"http://www.catholic.com/radio/shows/the-protestants-dilemma-
11565","audiourl":"http://www.catholic.com/sites/default/files/audio/radioshows/ca140331b.mp3"
,"datetime":"1396317600","description":" <<<- Here
Devin Rose
```

Remove that and that property will become a valid string, therefore you'll be able to stringify it

Comment: Oh, sorry for the downvote, the code in the question worked but not in the JSFiddle.